# What is serverless? If the AWS Lambda and API Gateway use servers then Why are they called 'Serverless'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, aws-serverless

I am testing AWS Lambda and API Gateway. I read that they are used in serverless infrastructure of AWS because end-users don't have to set up or manage servers.

But to my knowledge, AWS Lamda stores code in AWS, and API Gateway stores APIs in AWS. Don't they use servers to store data and process data? I think they are using some servers like EC2 to handle requests. Then why are they called serverless?

Are they called serverless on user's perspective?

**I want to know if they are truly serverless. And if so, how do they manage to do that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are they called serverless on user's perspective?

Yes, it is for the End user, who wants to run functions on AWS Lambda. User does not have to provision servers/VMs/Containers for it. AWS abstracts the hardware and the kind of hardware on which the functions will execute. It can execute it on a EC2 server or on a container running on ECS or some other way.

Suppose if the VM goes down, AWS can choose a new VM to execute the Lambda functions on, auto scaling is also taken care of.

Some one has to provision and manage servers, in this case AWS takes care of it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Many ones have the same confusion, **Why it's called serverless if the code is running on a server**.

**The shortest answer is**: Serverless is basically an event-driven, utility-based, stateless, and code execution environment. It's a cloud-native development model that allows developers to build and run applications without having to manage servers.

**A few key points are below:**

1. The main reason is developers do not need to be concerned with the server. The service provider/AWS handles the routine work of provisioning, maintaining, and scaling the server infrastructure.
2. The Developer will work on the business logic and can focus on his business logic. AWS operates serverless instances, can focus on running all workloads, automatic scaling, built-in high availability.
3. If any VM goes down, AWS can up a new VM to execute the Lambda functions. So you don't need to think about the server scaling, high ability, or other things.
4. The application logic does not have a web server waiting for requests. Instead, Multiple works execute when an event triggers/occurs.

Many things can trigger an event. Here are some examples:

- Web request to an API gateway: HTTP endpoints as Event sources for
  AWS Lambda Functions.
- Time of day or regular interval: Scheduler can
  be triggered when an event occurs
- Trigger an internal event: For example, File uploaded to S3 (object storage)
- Log event: Can be triggered to AWS cloud watch event for the logs.

To know more Details about serverless architecture, you can check [link1](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/) and [*Link2*](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/serverless-architectures-learn-more/)