# Are AWS Lambda functions actually EC2 instances under the hood?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I’ve heard that AWS security groups are essentially firewalls that can be applied to EC2 instances. Since you can apply security groups to many things in AWS, including Lambdas, I’m wondering if many serverless technologies in AWS are actually EC2 instances under the hood.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is serverless? If the AWS Lambda and API Gateway use servers then Why are they called 'Serverless'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279642/what-is-serverless-if-the-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-use-servers-then-why-are-t)

Comment: What it looks like is described [here](https://youtu.be/xmacMfbrG28?t=2580).

Answer (score 4):

Everything "serverless" has to run on a server at some point. The term "serverless" just means you, the end user, don't have to know about or care about what server those things are running on.

Yes many services, [including AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/firecracker-lightweight-virtualization-for-serverless-computing/), ultimately run on EC2 servers behind the scenes. They aren't EC2 servers in your AWS account though, they are EC2 servers managed by Amazon, that happen to be running your software on them.

Comment: Is there any info on which ec2 instance types lambdas are running on?